# Server is not responding to ping of client

Tags: nginx, signalr.client, asp.net-core-signalr

i have a react native application which is use signalR communicated with .net core 2.1.

There is not any error with socket connections. Works well all of things. But server can't respond the pings of client and returns 504 to client. When returns 504, client's connection close. Handled at hubConnection.onClose() . Then client needs to reconnect.

The proxy_read_timeout can setting to high milliseconds. But its messy.

So i can't use keepAliveInterval efficiently on client.

nginx conf settings;

```
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection $http_connection;

            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect off;
```

singalR configure on server;

```
        app.UseSignalR(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapHub<MyHub>("/myhub");
        });
```

nginx response(504) as below

> 2020/12/08 09:11:52 [error] 21#21: *2310 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, request: "GET /myhub?id=isXnVpd94uaaPOPucXS74Q&_=1607412351952 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://xx:5000/myhub?id=isXnVpd94uaaPOPucXS74Q&_=1607412351952"
>
> [08/Dec/2020:09:11:52 +0000] "GET
> /myhub?id=isXnVpd94uaaPOPucXS74Q&_=1607412351952 HTTP/1.1" 504 160 "-"
> "xx/326 CFNetwork/1206 Darwin/20.1.0" "-"

i can't understand why server does not respond the ping of client?

Comment: Are you sure than you server and the company who provides your hosting/server allow pings ?

Comment: I am not sure. Is there any option to allow pings?

Comment: What's your hosting provider ? Do you have a local firewall on your server ?

Comment: hosted at AWS. Using security groups instead of ufw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> AWS security groups block ICMP (including ping, traceroute, etc.) by
> default. You need to explicitly enable it.

[https://serverfault.com/questions/511738/why-cant-i-ping-my-freshly-set-up-amazon-web-service-ec2-instance#:~:text=by%20default.,need%20to%20explicitly%20enable%20it.&text=You%20need%20to%20add%20a,and%20click%20%22Add%20Rule%22](https://serverfault.com/questions/511738/why-cant-i-ping-my-freshly-set-up-amazon-web-service-ec2-instance#:%7E:text=by%20default.,need%20to%20explicitly%20enable%20it.&text=You%20need%20to%20add%20a,and%20click%20%22Add%20Rule%22).

Comment: Thank you!. I was really wondering why the server was not responding.

Comment: you are welcome. For info, a lot of hosting providers block ICMP/Ping and often Mail (port 25) by default.

Comment: thank you for information :) Have a nice day sir!